# How to define default settings for each connection in a connection pool with Knex.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js, node-oracledb

I need to set for each connection in a connection pool default session configurations like TIME_ZONE, LNS_DATE_LANGUAGE and others for Oracle database. Knex.js documentation provide a [snippet](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling-afterCreate) demonstrated below but for PostgreSQL:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {hos: ''},
  pool: {
    afterCreate: function (conn, done) {
      // in this example we use pg driver's connection API
      conn.query('SET timezone="UTC";', function (err) {
        if (err) {
          // first query failed, return error and don't try to make next query
          done(err, conn);
        } else {
          // do the second query...
          conn.query('SELECT set_limit(0.01);', function (err) {
            // if err is not falsy, connection is discarded from pool
            // if connection aquire was triggered by a query the error is passed to query promise
            done(err, conn);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The [oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/) way of doing that is defining a callback for the [`sessionCallback`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/sessiontagging1.js) attribute:

```
async function init() {
  try {
    await oracledb.createPool({
      user: 'USER',
      password: 'PWD',
      connectString: 'HOST:1521/SERVICE',
      sessionCallback: initSession //HERE MY DEFAULT SETTINGS
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

async function initSession(connection, requestedTag, cb) {
  try {
    await connection.execute(`
      ALTER SESSION SET 
      TIME_ZONE='UTC'
      NLS_LANGUAGE = 'BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE'
      NLS_TERRITORY = 'BRAZIL'
      NLS_CURRENCY = 'R$'
      NLS_ISO_CURRENCY = 'BRAZIL'
      NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.'
      NLS_CALENDAR = 'GREGORIAN'
      NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY'
      NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE'
      NLS_SORT = 'WEST_EUROPEAN'
      NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
      NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY = 'R$'
    `);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    cb(e);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      await connection.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able of translating this snippet above for a Knex.js implementation. **How to do that?**

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Também estou precisando setar algumas coisas na conexão do knex com o oracle.

Answer (score -1):

Does your KNEX use Oracle DB's connection pool?? https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/2665 show it as a future project.

Try the pg snippet you posted, buyt using the ALTER SESSION from your other example.

Comment: Those connections passed to afterCreate are database driver library's native connection objects. So if you meant that when asking "Does your KNEX use Oracle DB's connection pool??" the answer is yes. So just changing passed SQL of pg snippet will not work, because conn object is from oracledb driver not from knex / pg.

Comment: There's no call to `createPool()` in the Knex master branch, so I think the connections are standalone and not Oracle's connection-pool connections.   `afterConnect` seems to be a generic to Knex / tarn , so check again whether you can use that snippet

Comment: Indeed `afterConnect` is implemented in knex side (not in Tarn). the connection object passed to it is obtained here https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/lib/dialects/oracledb/index.js#L104  So it seems to be oracledb's standalone connection. Here is an example how to execute queries through it https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionhandling It does not have `conn.query(...)` method